# Resolve JDBC Oracle Index Column Names

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Hi is there a possibility to resolve the real column names from a index?
I use:

```
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(String, String, String, boolean, boolean)
```

But i get somthing like this:

```
[table=LOG_EMAIL, name=LOG_EMAIL_USERS_ID, columns=[SYS_NC00011$ A], unique=false]
```

How can i resolve the: *SYS_NC00011$*

I use *ojdbc6-11.2.0.4*

Comment: Why do you need it? And why do you use JDBC API? The column name looks it's "coocked" name for some functional index. Try to use dbms_metadata.get_ddl.

Comment: I need it to check ERM vs DB. And i use JDBC cause we use also other DBs.

Comment: I'm afraid it can not be done using JDBC API. You will need some database vendor dependent part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That index is a function based (expression) index.

The expression that is referenced by that name is stored in the system view `user_ind_expressions`:

```
select column_expression
from user_ind_expressions
where index_name = 'LOG_EMAIL_USERS_ID'
  and column_position = 1;
```

If you have more than one expression in the index you have multiple rows in `user_ind_expressions` with different values for `column_position` (the first expression is 1, the second is 2 and so on). The name `SYS_NC00011$` will not show up in that view.

Comment: Do you also know where I can find the sorting? Oracle returns null instead of A or D for function based indizes.

Comment: That should be the value of the column `ORDINAL_POSITION` returned by `getIndexInfo()` - but I'm not sure if the column_position refers to all columns in an index or just the function based ones.

Comment: it isn't "ORDINAL_POSITION short => column sequence number within index; zero when TYPE is tableIndexStatistic " it should be: "ORDINAL_POSITION short => column sequence number within index; zero when TYPE is tableIndexStatistic ".... it's null but it should be desc

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ResultSetMetadata -

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  System.out.println(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i));

}
```

Comment: And how exactly will `ResultSetMetaData` return information about an index on a table?